# No me deja ejecutar el codigo de Go en Visual Studio

Tags: rutas, go

Me pasa esto al querer ejecutar el codigo en Go

[image: Problema]

[image: Problema]

```
Starting: C:\Users\Matias\go\bin\dlv-dap.exe dap --check-go-version=false --listen=127.0.0.1:50115 from C:\Users\Matias\go\src\github.com\Matias\go_crash_course
DAP server listening at: 127.0.0.1:50115
Build Error: go test -c -o C:\Users\Matias\go\src\github.com\Matias\go_crash_course\__debug_bin.exe -gcflags all=-N -l .
go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules' (exit status 1)
```

[image: Problema3]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Estaba bien que hayas compartido el error como texto, de hecho, [con esta edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/294623) se veía mucho mejor.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de go estás utilizando?

Comment: La 1.71.1 -----

Comment: Quiero aclarar que esto me pasa con todos los lenguajes de programacion como por ejemplo Rust

Answer (score 1):

Te falta inicializar el módulo.

Ejecuta...

`go mod init {nombre de tu modulo o carpeta}`

Te debería crear el archivo go.mod